# How can I extract the SAN's inside a .csr file in node.js (Serverless Framework)?

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, pki, csr, node-forge

Using Serverless Framework with node.js, I need to read information inside a .csr file received via http POST. Using the [node-forge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge) module, and with the following code, I was able to extract the different information that composes the certificate signing request:

```
const forge = require('node-forge');
...
var csr = forge.pki.certificationRequestFromPem(cert);
console.log(csr.subject.attributes)

if(csr.subject.getField('CN'))
  var CN = csr.subject.getField('CN').value

if(csr.subject.getField('SAN'))
  var SAN = csr.subject.getField('SAN').value

 if(csr.subject.getField('O'))
  var O = csr.subject.getField('O').value

if(csr.subject.getField('OU'))
  var OU = csr.subject.getField('OU').value

if(csr.subject.getField('C'))
  var C = csr.subject.getField('C').value

if(csr.subject.getField('ST'))
  var S = csr.subject.getField('ST').value

if(csr.subject.getField('L'))
  var L = csr.subject.getField('L').value

if(csr.subject.getField('E'))
  var E = csr.subject.getField('E').value
```

What I need right now is to also extract the SAN's of the CSR if they exist, problem is that after inspecting the `x509.js` file ("Javascript implementation of X.509 and related components (such as
Certification Signing Requests) of a Public Key Infrastructure") that comes within the module, I dot not think there is a way to extract the SAN's:

```
// short name OID mappings
var _shortNames = {};
_shortNames['CN'] = oids['commonName'];
_shortNames['commonName'] = 'CN';
_shortNames['C'] = oids['countryName'];
_shortNames['countryName'] = 'C';
_shortNames['L'] = oids['localityName'];
_shortNames['localityName'] = 'L';
_shortNames['ST'] = oids['stateOrProvinceName'];
_shortNames['stateOrProvinceName'] = 'ST';
_shortNames['O'] = oids['organizationName'];
_shortNames['organizationName'] = 'O';
_shortNames['OU'] = oids['organizationalUnitName'];
_shortNames['organizationalUnitName'] = 'OU';
_shortNames['E'] = oids['emailAddress'];
_shortNames['emailAddress'] = 'E';
```

Am I using a deprecated module or old version? Is there a way for me to achieve this and I'm simply using the incorrect stuff inside node-forge?

Please let me know if anyone had a similar problem or was able to overcome this issue. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to solve this with the following code:

```
var csr = forge.pki.certificationRequestFromPem(cert);
var altNames = csr.attributes.find(t=>t.name === 'extensionRequest').extensions.find(t=>t.name === 'subjectAltName').altNames;
```

I created a dummy certificate with SANs and Apparently node-forge extracts that information and places them inside `extensionRequest -> subjectAltNames`. I have these hardcoded since I'm assuming these attribute names will not change, but I can't be 100% sure about it.

Hope this helps someone who might have gone through this issue. Thank you.